# C: warns about implicit long to int conversion

Tags: c, compiler-construction, gcc-warning

I was wondering whether there is a way to tell the compiler (I'm on gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46) or icc 11.1) to throw a warning whenever a long-to-int implicit conversion takes place. For example, compiling the file `test.c` which contains the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = atol(argv[1]);
    printf("int: %d\n", n);
    long int N = atol(argv[1]);
    printf("long: %ld\n", N);

    return 0;
}
```

with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wconversion test.c -o test
```

does not produce any warnings. Running the resulting binary as

```
./test 12345678901
```

I get, as expected:

```
int: -539222987
long: 12345678901
```

as the number 12345678901 has overflown the int but not the long.
I'd like the compiler to tell me whenever something like this might happen. The option -Wconversion unexpectedly (to me) does not do that.

Thanks,

Michele

Answer (score 4):

Check if your gcc version has `-Wshorten-64-to-32`.  Be prepared for a deluge of possibly spurious double -> float conversion warnings if you use floating-point in your code.

**edit:** I think `shorten-64-to-32` may be an Apple extension that mainline never picked up, sadly.  So you may be out of luck unless you upgrade to gcc-4.3 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Try gcc 4.3.0

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, six years after :)

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `-Wconversion` [changed with GCC4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) - update your compiler and try again (can't check if it really works myself as I'm on a 32bit system, but as the warning gets correctly emitted for `atoll`, it should)...